# Should I mutate a passed-in property or assign its result?

Tags: functional-programming

Suppose I need a method that adds `1` to a given number. Which of these two ways is more correct in a functional programming paradigm?

**Option A: Immutable Assignment**

```
function addOneToB(input) { return input + 1; }
var a = { b: 5 };
a.b = addOneToB(a.b);
```

**Option B: Pure Mutation**

```
function addOneToB(input) { input.b++ }
var a = { b: 5 };
addOneToB(a);
```

It seems to me that both options are sufficiently pure for strict FP, but it feels like option B is 'cleaner' because the entire operation is undertaken inside the method, not inside (doing the arithmetic) and outside (assigning the result).

Comment: Neither. You should discard original object and create a new immutable one.

Comment: I believe that's what's happening to the value of `b` in the first option.

Comment: Object 'a' is mutated.

Answer (score 3):

You shouldn't do any of those - both are mutating `a`, so neither is "pure".

In the second version, the "function" is even mutating its argument instead of returning a value.

This is a "pure" version of the first variant:

```
function addOne(input) { return input + 1; }
var a = { b: 5 };
var c = { b: addOne(a.b) } ;
```

and the second one:

```
function addOneToB(input) { return { b: input.b + 1}; }
var a = { b: 5 };
var c = addOneToB(a);
```